# MS Excel. How to filter a pivot table based on input range?

Tags: microsoft-excel, pivot-table

I know that I can go to Row Label filter –> Value Filters –> Greater Than etc. However, I'd like to have two input fields, From and To and I'd like for the pivot table to only display values within this range. Is this possible?

Comment: Where did you input the field? could you provide a simple sample?

Comment: @Lee I'd like the input fields outside of the pivot table. I don't want the customer to have to make changes to the pivot table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

1. Create a new column (e.g. Filter_check) in a source data with formula comparing filter fields "From" and "To" with a data field in the source data range with output format True/False (e.g. `=if({data field}>={Field from}, if({data field}<={Field to}, TRUE, FALSE), FALSE)`)
2. Update a source range data of your pivot table and add the new column.
3. Set column "Filter_check" as a Filter
4. In the filter set TRUE value
5. Next create a macro for updating a worksheet after every change

MACRO:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
   application.EnableEvents=False
   ActiveWorkbook.RefreshAll
   application.EnableEvents=True 
End Sub
```

When you change values in fields "From" and "To" it should work.

Best regards, Lukas

Comment: Thank you @Muji
I'm wanting to have input cells for to and from in the dashboard. I'd like the pivot to pull in the values from these input fields, is this possible?

Comment: Hi @sonic99, I have updated the comment. You can try it. Best regards, Lukas

Comment: Wow! That is so clever! I will try and see how it goes. Thank you @Muji

Comment: Hi @sonic99, any news?

Comment: That worked! Thank you, @Muji
I just need to get the Macro to work now :)

Comment: The macro I placed in the comment works, doesn't it? Don't you know how to create it? You must show developer tab in Excel options and open Visual Basic from "Code" section of the tab. Then open the sheet where your input cells are placed and insert the code inside. Then save and that is. The Excel spreadsheet should be saved as xlsm format (supported macros).