# How to create a chart that uses cell information like a pivot chart slicer

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts

I have a page that has data aggregrates. The user will have to enter what brand it wants information calculated for. Then eventually, this will allow multiple charts to filter per this brand. That is my hope, at least.

I am unsure how to do this with a normal chart. I know how to do this with a PivotTable/PivotChart by using a slicer. However, the issue with this method is that I will have multiple charts. Therefore, if using a PivotTable/Chart method, I will need multiple slicers that ask for the brand information every time.

How can I add a non-Pivot Table chart that can use the "Brand" cell shown in the picture to pull only information for that brand?

The second photo contains the "Averages" sheet that I would want to pull the information for.

[image]

[image]

**UPDATE**

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: A simple method is adding a formula column to your data like `=IF(B4=[@[BRAND]], TRUE, FALSE)` where `B4` is your brand cell, then slice/filter on that field using True in your chart. Optionally include a macro to update the charts when you edit the cell value: https://superuser.com/a/1481051/673426.

Comment: @Cpt.Whale Are you saying to do something like this? Last two pics in the question. I added it, but I don't know how I can filter the true value in the chart itself.

Comment: Can you simply use VLOOKUP formulas based on the one Brand selection? Such as have the data from resulting vlookup hidden behind each chart.

Comment: @Isolated Are you saying to add that in here? See new pic in question.

Comment: No, I'm just wondering if you can have have multiple VLOOKUP formulas for populating the data that is used for creating the charts. So if you have 3 charts, create 3 formulas. I'm just not sure entirely on your structure and desired output.

Comment: @Isolated Gotcha. The data that I am showing above is using a lookup function of sorts to populate the data already. I'm not sure if having a chart for each makes sense because it wouldn't change per brand selection. For instance, I will have a chart for leads. sales. activities, etc. But it is all bound by the brand selected.

Comment: That's what I mean. Someone select the Brand, then the formulas go do their thing based on that brand. So one might be a vlookup, maybe another a sumifs, etc. But they all use that brand.

Comment: @Paul my method was for pivot charts. You can technically do the same thing using a (non-pivot) table with a column filter, but you have to reapply filter (ctrl+alt+L on a cell in that column) to update the charts when the Brand cell value changes, which is more annoying than "refresh all"

Comment: @Cpt.Whale So, I am trying to add the custom field, but it keeps populating a "syntax of this name isn't correct error". Does anything look off you to? I added a pic in the question.

Comment: @Paul ah, I meant adding a field to the source table (Averages?), and filter/slice using that field in the pivot table

Comment: You could write a Dynamic Array formula using FILTER() and base your chart on the results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple method is adding a column to your data with a formula like `=IF(B4=[@[BRAND]], TRUE, FALSE)` where B4 is your brand cell, then slice/filter on that field using True in your chart. Optionally include a macro to update the charts when you edit the cell value: https://superuser.com/a/1481051/673426.

Here's my example using a simple table. The table is filtered to `Filter=TRUE`.

[image: screenshot]

If I change `B1` to 'banana' AND reapply the table filter, the chart updates:

[image]

Here's an example macro to auto update using a simple table. I've added a `msgbox` line so you can tell when it runs, but you can remove that:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
   Application.EnableEvents = False
   Worksheets("Sheet1").ListObjects("Table1").AutoFilter.ApplyFilter
   MsgBox "refreshed"
   Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

This has to be added to the Sheet where you are entering the brand because it will only run when **that** sheet changes.

[image]

Comment: Thank you. I got the filter working correctly. I went with a normal table/chart and ditched the Pivot table. However, I can't get the macro to work. I entered it just as the other question wrote it because I didn't see any variable code to modify. Any ideas there?

Comment: @Paul The linked answer was for pivot tables as well (refresh vs re-apply). For simple tables, the vba would be `ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table1").AutoFilter.ApplyFilter` using the table name to refresh

Comment: @Paul oh yep, `ActiveSheet` does only mean the sheet that's currently open. You would pick from other sheets like so instead: `Worksheets("Sheet1").ListObjects("Table1").Range.AutoFilter.ApplyFilter`

Comment: Thanks. I tried adding this, but still no luck. I added a photo above to add clarity to what I am doing. I tried swapping the sheet names in the worksheets and listobjects field. No luck doing that either.

Comment: @Paul in this case, you would use `Worksheets("Averages")` as the sheet where your data is located, then `Table1` should be the name of the actual table object your data is in (you can see these names by going to the Formulas tab > Defined Names section > Name Manager).

Comment: So, I changed to Averages and found the table name, renamed it and used that name. After changing the brand name, nothing is happening on my chart or on the table itself. `Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
   Application.EnableEvents = False
   ActiveWorkbook.RefreshAll
   Application.EnableEvents = True
   Worksheets("Averages").ListObjects("LeadTable").Range.AutoFilter.ApplyFilter
End Sub`

Comment: @Paul I made a typo earlier. I've added some example code that works for me to my answer - make sure to change the sheet/table names. You may need to save the file as .xlsb and re-open

Comment: Thank you for all of your help. This worked!